# Preimage of zero measure sets

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a set of Lebesgue measure zero and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function. Under what conditions does $f^{-1}(A)$ have Lebesgue measure zero?

I  found a possible answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128477/preimage-of-zero-measure-sets) but I cannot fully understand the proof. The claim is that $f\in C^1$ and the set $\{x:\ \nabla f(x)=0\}$ having measure zero suffices. Now the proof given starts with: "To prove this, note that this is true locally, in a neighborhood of each point where $\nabla f(x)\neq 0$, due to the implicit function theorem." Take a point $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\nabla f(x)\neq 0$ and $f(x)=c$ for some $c\in A$. By the implicit function theorem one can find neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ of $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})$ and $x_n$ respectively such that $f^{-1}(\{c\})\cap (U\times V)=\{(y,g(y)):y\in U\}$ for some function $g$ on $U$ and $\nabla f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in U\times V$. But what about all the other elments of $A$?

A reference on this or similar theorem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I need to know this too!

Comment: No, I did not. I ended up proving a very special case which was enough at the time.

Comment: For those wondering, there was a follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215996/if-f%E2%88%88c1-and-%E2%88%87f-0-has-lebesgue-measure-0-then-f%E2%88%88b-has-lebesgue