# If $f∈C^1$ and $\{∇f=0\}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$, then $\{f∈B\}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ for all Borel measurable $B⊆ℝ$ with Lebesgue measure $0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, differential-geometry, lebesgue-measure, implicit-function-theorem

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $f\in C^1(\mathbb R^d)$. Assume $\left\{\nabla f=0\right\}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.

> How can we conclude that $\left\{f\in B\right\}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ for all Borel measurable $B\subseteq\mathbb R$ with Lebesgue measure $0$?

The claim can be found in an [answer on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/128482/91890).

The author writes that the claim "is true locally, in a neighborhood of each point where $\nabla f\ne0$, due to the implicit function theorem". Honestly, I don't even understand what exactly he's meaning.

Let $a\in\mathbb R^d$ with $\nabla f(a)\ne0$. Then surely, by continuity of $\nabla f$ at $a$, there is an open neighborhood $N$ of $a$ with $$\nabla f(x)\ne0\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in N\tag1.$$ But how do we need to apply the implicit function theorem and what's the resulting "local" conclusion? Maybe that $N\cap\left\{f\in B\right\}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$?

Comment: Yes you need to prove that $N\cap\{f\in B\}$ has measure $0$. If you show this the result follows, because there is a countable family of open sets $\{B_i\}$ covering $\Bbb R^d$ such that $B_i\cap\{f\in B\}$ has measure $0$. Then $\mu(\{f\in B\})=\sum_i \mu(\{f\in B\}\cap B_i)=0$.

Comment: @AdamChalumeau Thank you for the clarification. I'm struggling to understand how we need to apply the implicit function theorem (I'm sure it's easy).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Non-singular maps.** A map $f\,:\,\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^M$ whose inverse image preserves null-sets, -- i.e., $\mu(f^{-1}(B))=0$ for any null-set $B$, -- is often referred to as a non-singular map. The question is about showing that the class of $\mathcal{C}^1$ maps with non-singular Jacobian (or more specifically, non-zero gradient) almost everywhere is contained in the class of non-singular maps.

---

> **Remark.** $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is called a regular value of $f\in\mathcal{C}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, if $\nabla f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in f^{-1}(c)$.
>   The Implicit Function Theorem (IFT) asserts that $f^{-1}(c)$ is a (d-1)-dimensional submanifold of
>   class $\mathcal{C}^1$ -- for any regular value $c$. Hence, $f^{-1}(c)$
>   is a null-set.

Let $\widetilde{N}\overset{\Delta}=\left\{\nabla f\neq 0\right\}$ (which is open).

From the IFT, we have that $\widetilde{N}\cap f^{-1}(c)$ is a (d-1)-submanifold of class $\mathcal{C}^1$.

Now, you have $\widetilde{N}\cap \left\{f\in B\right\}=\bigcup_{t\in B}\widetilde{N} \cap f^{-1}(t)$, where $\widetilde{N} \cap f^{-1}(t)$ is a null-set for all $t$ from the above remark (since it is a $\mathcal{C}^1$ submanifold from the IFT). Therefore, when $B$ is countable, the referred set is a null-set.

When $B$ is uncountable, it follows from Fubini's Theorem that $\bigcup_{t\in B}\widetilde{N}\cap B_r \cap f^{-1}(t)$ is a null-set for any bounded open ball $B_r$.

To see this latter claim, we can resort to a more specialized form of Fubini tailored to our case (referred to as [co-area formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula)),

$\int_{\widetilde{N}\cap B_r} g\left|\nabla f\right| d\mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{f^{-1}(t)\cap\widetilde{N}\cap B_r} g(x)d\mu_{d-1}(x)\right) dt$.

Take $g$ to be the indicator of the *foliation* $\bigcup_{t\in B}\widetilde{N}\cap B_r \cap f^{-1}(t)$ and note that

$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{f^{-1}(t)\cap\widetilde{N}\cap B_r} g(x)d\mu_{d-1}(x)\right) dt=\int_{B} \left(\int_{f^{-1}(t)\cap\widetilde{N}\cap B_r} d\mu_{d-1}(x)\right) dt=0$,

where the last identity holds since $B$ is a null-set. Thus,

$\int_{\widetilde{N}\cap B_r} g\left|\nabla f\right| d\mu=0$ and therefore $g\left|\nabla f\right|=0$ almost everywhere in $\widetilde{N}\cap B_r$. Since, $\left|\nabla f\right|\neq 0$ almost everywhere, it follows that $g(x)=0$ almost everywhere in $\widetilde{N}\cap B_r$. In other words,

$\mu\left(\bigcup_{t\in B}\widetilde{N}\cap B_r \cap f^{-1}(t)\right)=\int g d\mu =0$.

---

**Update.** For the sake of completeness, I am adding the general statement.

> **Theorem 1.** Let $f\,:\,\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^M$ be smooth
>   (i.e., $f\in\mathcal{C}^1$). If the set of critical points of $f$ is
>   a null-set, i.e.,
>
> $\mu\left(\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^N : \text{rank} \left(Df(x)\right)<\min\left\{M,N\right\}\right\}\right)=0,$
>
> then, $\mu\left(f^{-1}(B)\right)=0$ for any null-set $B$.

The proof follows from the [IFT](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/regular-and-critical-points/) and [Fubini (or, more precisely, the co-area formula)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula) just as done before.

---

**Update 2.** I am adding a Corollary.

**Definition. [Null-sets on manifolds]** Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $d$ with smooth structure $\left\{U_{\alpha},\varphi_{\alpha}\right\}$. $A\subset \mathcal{V}$ is called a null subset of $\mathcal{V}$ if $\mu\left(\varphi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}\cap A)\right)=0$ for all $\alpha$.

**Relevant Property.** If $\mu(\widehat{A})=0$ with $\widehat{A}\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ then,
$\varphi^{-1}_{\alpha}(\widehat{A})$ is a null-set for any $\alpha$. This follows by observing that $\varphi_{\beta}\left(U_{\beta}\cap\varphi^{-1}_{\alpha}(\widehat{A})\right)=\varphi_{\beta}\circ \varphi^{-1}_{\alpha}(\widehat{A})$ is necessarily a null-set, for any $\beta$, since $\widehat{A}$ is a null-set and $\varphi_{\beta}\circ \varphi^{-1}_{\alpha}$ is a diffeomorphism -- hence, from Theorem 1, $\varphi_{\beta}\circ \varphi^{-1}_{\alpha}(\widehat{A})$ is a null-set.

In the next corollary, we assume that the manifolds admit countable atlas -- i.e., are separable.

> **Corollary 1.** Let $f\,:\,\mathcal{M}\rightarrow \mathcal{N}$ be a smooth map
>   between two smooth separable manifolds $\mathcal{M}$, $\mathcal{N}$ of dimensions $M$ and $N$, respectively. If the set of critical points of $f$ is a null-set, then $f^{-1}(B)$ is a null-set for any null-set $B$.

For the proof, one just needs to notice that any local coordinate representation of $f$ fulfills the conditions of Theorem 1.

Comment: It's a bit unfortunate that you redefined the symbol $N$ which is already used in the question.

Comment: Something is wrong in your post: (a) $f$ is a real-valued function. So, the notation $f^{-1}(c)$ (which I suppose is a shorthand for $f^{-1}(\{c\})$) is undefined. (b) Isn't a regular value defined to be the opposite of a critical/stationary point? (So, $a\in\mathbb R^d$ is a regular point of $f$ iff $\nabla f(a)\ne 0$. In this case, as mentioned in the question, there is a neighborhood $N$ of $a$ with $(1)$.) I guess you confused this with the notion of a regular *value* of $f$ which is precisely defined as the image of $f$ at a regular point.

Comment: If I am not missing anything, the $N$ you have in your question, is contained in the $N$ I have in my answer; (a) $f^{-1}(c)=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,:\,f(x)=c \right\}$ refers to the inverse image of $c\in\mathbb{R}$ by $f$. Yes, one should rather write $f^{-1}(\left\{c\right\})$; (b) what is relevant is that $f^{-1}(c)$ is a surface whenever $c$ fulfills the above characterizing property (that I am referring in this case as regular).

Comment: Yes, sure, but if I'm reading other questions I find it highly confusing if symbols are defined more than once.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how exactly we obtain that $f^{-1}(c)$ is a $(d-1)$-dimensional submanifold by the IFT? Since this is the only crucial part I don't understand (and actually the reason why I asked this question).

Comment: This is one possible formulation of the IFT (I have a reference with this explicit theorem, but it is in portuguese). You can also find it here: https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/regular-and-critical-points/

Comment: It's clear to me that any submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with dimension less than $d$ is a null set. Since $\tilde N$ is assumed to be a null set, $\tilde N\cap\{f=c\}$ is a null set for each regular value $c$ of $f$. But it's not clear to me how you conclude that $\bigcup_{x\in B}\tilde N \cap\{f=x\}$ is a null set. Actually, since this might be an uncountable union, it's not even clear to me why it is measurable.

Comment: Just to make sure, $\widetilde{N}$ is an open set (hence not null). $\widetilde{N}\cap \left\{f=c\right\}$ is a null-set because it is necessarily a manifold: $c$ is a regular value of $f\,:\,\widetilde{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (though not necessarily of $f\,:\,\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$). Regarding your last question: of course this might be an uncountable union -- hence we cannot claim that it is a null-set from simple $\sigma$-additivity. First, note that $\widetilde{N}\cap \left\{f\in B\right\}$ is measurable because:

Comment: $\widetilde{N}$ (an open set) is measurable and $\left\{f\in B\right\}$ is measurable (by assumption $B$ is Borel-measurable). Further, we can observe that: $\mu\left(\bigcup_{x\in B} \widetilde{N}\cap f^{-1}(x)\right)= \int_B g(x)dx$, where I have defined $g(x)\overset{\Delta}=\mu\left(\widetilde{N}\cap f^{-1}(x)\right)$.

Comment: Just one slight clarification (as my notation in the previous comment is not the best): $g(x)$ is the surface integral of $\widetilde{N}\cap f^{-1}(x)$ and not the ambient Lebesgue measure of $\widetilde{N}\cap f^{-1}(x)$ (which is zero).

Comment: Sorry, I confused $\tilde N$ with its complement. I don't understand your notation. What is $\mu$? If it's a measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$, then we still need to know that $\bigcup_{x\in B}(\tilde N\cap\{f=x\})$ is measurable ... Is it somehow easier to show that $N\cap\left\{f\in B\right\}$ (with $N$ given in the question) is a null set in the first place (as suggested in the mathoverflow answer)? At least it would be easy to conclude from that (since by separability, there is a countable system of such $N$).

Comment: Would be great if you could elaborate on this last question. Please take note of my comments below the other answer as well.

Comment: Couple of things: i) $\bigcup_{x\in B}\left(\widetilde{N}\cap \left\{f=x\right\}\right)$ is measurable because $\bigcup_{x\in B}\left(\widetilde{N}\cap \left\{f=x\right\}\right)=\widetilde{N}\cap \left\{f\in B\right\}$ and as I referred before, the right hand side of the latter is measurable; ii) We need not Fubini, but this [stronger result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula) to conclude that the *foliation* $\bigcup_{x\in B}\left(\widetilde{N}\cap \left\{f=x\right\}\right)$ is a null-set; iii) in fact, in view of this result

Comment: we need to constraint ourselves to bounded neighborhoods $N$ as you give in the question, but bounded (so that $\left|\nabla f\right|$ is bounded over the neighborhood -- please, check the first equation in the wiki link that I pointed in the previous comment). Note that in the first equation of the link I pointed, you just need to replace $g$ by the indicator function of $\bigcup_{x\in B} \left(\widetilde{N}\cap \left\{f=x\right\}\right)$. I will update the answer tomorrow.

Comment: In my second to last comment I meant 'specialized result' from Fubini (and not stronger).

Comment: I've found the result for general Hausdorff measures. However, I'm not familiar with general Hausdorff measures. I only know the concept of submanifolds of $\mathbb R^d$, compact sets with smooth boundary and the surface measure on submanifolds. Do you know a reference where such a special case is proved? An example which is clear to me is $$\int f(x)\:{\rm d}x=\int_0^\infty\int f\:{\rm d}\sigma_{\partial B_r(x_0)}\:{\rm d}r,$$ where $\sigma_{\partial B_r(x_0)}$ denotes the surface measure on $\mathcal B(\partial B_r(x_0))$.

Comment: For the co-area formula referred to in the answer, please check Theorem 3.11. in [Geometric Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions](http://doc.sciencenet.cn/upload/file/201792094427442.pdf). The (d-1)-Hausdorff measure $\mu_{d-1}$ coincides with the surface measure over smooth (d-1)-submanifolds -- have a look at Section 3.3 of the reference I pointed.

Comment: In particular, $\int_{f^{-1}(t)\cap\widetilde{N}\cap B_r} d\mu_{d-1}(x)$ is the surface area of $f^{-1}(t)\cap\widetilde{N}\cap B_r$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about the implicit function theorem, but you can a one related theorem, the [Local Submersion Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320102/local-submersion-theorem-differential-topology-of-guillemin-and-pollack). With your notations, locally around $a$, $f$ looks like a projections onto the first coordinate. You are left to prove that $$p:(x_1,\dots,x_d)\in\Bbb{R}^d\mapsto x_1$$
has the property that $$(B\text{ has measure zero})\Longrightarrow (\{p\in B\}\text{ has measure zero}).$$
But $\{p\in B\}=B\times\Bbb R^{d-1}$ so you can conclude.

Comment: You have to be careful with the degrees of smoothness: Usually, submersions are defined in the $C^\infty$ category, while OP is only assuming $C^1$. But Submersion theorem locally is the same as the Implicit Function Theorem.

Comment: I don't know the "local submersion theorem". However, the following is clear to me: If $M$ is a $k$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ and $a\in M$, there is an open neighborhood $U_a$ of $a$ and a $C^1$-diffeomorphism $\varphi_a$ from $U_a$ to an open subset $V_a$ of $\mathbb R^d$ with $$\varphi_a(U_a\cap M)=V_a\cap(\mathbb R^k\times\{0\})$$ and hence $U_a\cap M$ is Borel measurable and has Lebesgue measure $0$ (assuming $k<n$).

Comment: Moreover, it's clear to me that if $c\in\mathbb R$ is a regular value of $f$ (i.e. $c=f(a)$ for some $a\in\mathbb R^d$ with $\nabla f(a)\ne 0$), then $M_c:=\{f=c\}$ is a $(d-1)$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$. But I don't know how we can conclude from that for the same reason I don't see why we can conclude in the other answer. It would be clear if $\{f\in B\}=\bigcup_{c\in B}M_c$ would be a countable union.