# When is the pushforward absolutely continuous with respect to the base measure?

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, pushforward

## Context

I would like to find sufficient conditions such that $\upsilon^\psi\ll\upsilon$ where $\upsilon$ is a sigma-finite measure and $\psi$ is an invertible, measurable function.

## Idea/Attempt

Let $(\mathsf{Z}, \mathcal{Z})$ be a measurable space, and $\upsilon$ be a sigma-finite measure on it. Let $\psi:\mathsf{Z}\to\mathsf{Z}$ be $\mathcal{Z}$-measurable and invertible, with inverse $\psi^{-1}:\mathsf{Z}\to\mathsf{Z}$. We wish to show that for any $\mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{Z}$ we have
$$
\upsilon(\mathsf{A}) = 0 \implies \upsilon^\psi(\mathsf{A}).
$$
This reduces to showing that the preimages of $\upsilon$-null sets are $\upsilon$-null sets. I have browsed a few related questions such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657155/preimage-of-zero-measure-sets) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215996/if-f%E2%88%88c1-and-%E2%88%87f-0-has-lebesgue-measure-0-then-f%E2%88%88b-has-lebesgue) but they are much less general than my question. Here I am not dealing with $\upsilon$ being a Lebesgue measure and I am not assuming any Jacobian (although, that is a case that I am very much interested in).

I feel that geometric measure theory could come in handy, but after browsing for a bit, I could not find anything at this level of generality.

Comment: It seems to me that your question is equivalent to asking when the inverse $\psi^{-1}:Z\to Z$ has the Lusin $\mathsf{N}$-property with respect to $\mu$, that is, when $\mu(A)=0\implies \mu(\psi^{-1}(A))=0$. This is discussed in [Bogachev](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-34514-5).

Comment: @Snoop Thanks that's very helpful! However, in Bogachev $\mu$ has to be a Lebesgue, whereas in my case it's more general than that.